# unable to establish connection between Cloud foundary app and Cloud foundary service in IoT Platform

Tags: iot, node-red, cloudant

I have created a node-red and its started. On navigating to the connections section I see the DB is connected and its running however when I navigate to the DB the node connection does not appear over there hence I try to manually create connection and the below error appears, I'm not sure what is it that I'm missing out. I need to connect the node red and my mobile app with this DB only then the data would be flowed into node-red. 
[image: node-red]

Comment: If it's all working, what are you actually trying to change (and why)?

Comment: @hardillb I'm unable to send the data from device to the node-red , I mean that node-red is running.

Comment: The cloudant database is there to hold the Node-RED flow and settings, it is not linked to the Watson IoT service at all.

Comment: @hardillb ok, here there should have been a connection to the node-red if I'm correct

Comment: No, the database doesn't need to know where Node-RED is